# 関数やメソッドの引数の数を調べるにはどうすればいい？

Tags: php

実行時に、関数からその関数を実行せずに必要な引数の数を知るにはどうすれば良いですか?

```
<?php

function myFunc($a, $b, $c)
{
    return "$a, $b and $c!";
}
```

このような関数を定義したとき、`$a, $b, $c` という三つの引数を必要とするので「3」という数が知りたいです。

また、メソッドについても同じように調べられますか?

```
<?php

class Hoge
{
    public static function fuga ($a, $b)
    {
        return "fuga: $a and $b!";
    }

    public function piyo ($a, $b, $c)
    {
        return "piyo: $a, $b and $c!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHPの実行時にクラスや函数などの詳細な情報を取得するには[リフレクション](http://php.net/manual/book.reflection.php)といふ仕組を利用します。

今回のように函数の情報を知りたいときには、[ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionfunction.php)を利用することができます。

```
<?php

$func_ref = new ReflectionFunction("myFunc");
echo $func_ref->getNumberOfParameters() . PHP_EOL;
// 3
```

この仕組は、もちろんPHPの標準函数に対しても、[無名関数](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php)に対しても利用することができます。

メソッドは方法が少し違って、[ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionclass.php)から[ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionmethod.php)を取得します。

```
<?php

$c = new ReflectionClass("Hoge");
echo $c->getMethod("fuga")->getNumberOfParameters() . PHP_EOL;
// 2
echo $c->getMethod("piyo")->getNumberOfParameters() . PHP_EOL;
// 3

$d = new ReflectionClass(new Hoge);
echo $d->getMethod("fuga")->getNumberOfParameters() . PHP_EOL;
// 2
echo $d->getMethod("piyo")->getNumberOfParameters() . PHP_EOL;
// 3
```

`new ReflectionClass` はクラス名を渡す方法とインスタンスを渡す方法のどちらでも大丈夫です。

詳細については[PHP - 函数・クロージャの引数の個数を調べる - Qiita](http://qiita.com/tadsan/items/b539eab11fb6902c17f1)も併せて読んでください。

Answer (score -1):

リフレクションを使わなくても引数を動的に扱える関数があります。

http://php.net/manual/ja/function.func-get-args.php

配列で引数が取得できるので数えれば個数も分かりますし、好きな順番で扱うこともできます。
動的な処理を行うライブラリやフレームワーク的な実装をする際に昔から疲れている関数です。

Comment: 「渡された引数の数」ではなく、関数/メソッドが期待する仮引数の数[アリティ - Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3)を「実行せずに」知るのが今回の要件なので、 `func_get_args()` は期待するものではありません。